# Fundamental group of $\mathbb{S^n}$ for $n \ge 2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, spheres

What is wrong with following trivial argument in proving that fundamental groups of higher order spheres are trivial?

As we know $\mathbb{S^n} - p$ is **homeomorphic** to $\mathbb{R^n}$, where $p$ is pole of sphere.

So, all loops based on some point of sphere say $s$, not passing through $p$ will be **nullhomotopic** as $\mathbb{R^n}$ is convex space.

Now apply some rotation about any axis. Given new sphere will be **homeomorphic** to older one just with transformed pole from $p$ to $p'$ and now all loops based on $s$ passing through $p$ will also be **nullhomotopic**.

So, all loops based on $s$ are nullhomotopic and so $\pi_1(\mathbb{S^n},s) ={0}$

Comment: The problem is that there are surjective loops.

Comment: @DanielFischer I didn't understand. Can you please explain in more details ?

Comment: The argument works for loops that leave (at least) one point of $S^n$ out. But if the loop is surjective, you can't view it as a loop in $\mathbb{R}^n$ since removing a point of $S^2$ then destroys the loop.

Comment: There are loops that cover the entire sphere, but that's a non-issue as you can approximate one such map by one that it is not surjective, for example dividing the interval and approximating the segment $[a_i, b_i]$ in each sub-interval by a 'line' that connects the images of $a_i, b_i$.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Now, I got it. Thats precisely what Van Kampen theorem does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this argument is that there are loops $\alpha:I\to \mathbb{S}^n$ which are surjective, they cover entire sphere. Such loops are known as [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) and they exist for any $n\geq 1$ by the Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem. Such loops always pass through (any) $p\in \mathbb{S}^n$ regardless of applied rotation (or any other homeomorphism). And so there is no valid choice of $p$ (as a point that $\alpha$ misses).

However it is the case that every loop is homotopic to a non-surjective loop. You can apply the following reasoning [Proving directly that $S^2$ is simply connected: is a surjective loop homotopic to a non-surjective one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3276313/proving-directly-that-s2-is-simply-connected-is-a-surjective-loop-homotopic#answer-3277079) to any $S^n$ for $n\geq 2$. And with that missing piece your proof is complete.

Comment: Thank you for your response.