# Simply Connected-ness of $\mathbb S^2$ using $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Criticize the following "proof" that $\mathbb S^2$ is simply connected: Let $f$ be a loop in $\mathbb S^2$ based at $x_0$. Choose a point $p$ of $\mathbb S^2$ not lying in the image of $f$. Since $\mathbb S^2 -p$ is homeomorphic with $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^2$ is simply connected, the loop $f$ is path homotopic to the constant loop.

So when the author puts the word proof inside ”...” it means that given is not a proof but a fallacy. But I couldn't find anything wrong with this. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Why can you choose such a $p$ ?

Comment: Actually, the argument can be a little bit modified to work : look at : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3276313/proving-directly-that-s2-is-simply-connected-is-a-surjective-loop-homotopic

Comment: Yes. Got it. Thank you